# BASH Finding palindromes in a .txt file

Tags: bash, palindrome

I have been given a .txt file in which we have to find all the palindromes in the text (must have at least 3 letters and they cant be the same letters e.g. AAA)

it should be displayed with the first column being the amount of times it appears and the second being the word e.g.

> 123 kayak
>
> 3 bob
>
> 1 dad

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp='mktemp'

awk '{for(x=1;$x;++x)print $x}' "${1}" | tr -d [[:punct:]] | tr -s [:space:] | sed -e 's/@//g' -e 's/[0-9]*//g'| sed -r '/^.{,2}$/d' | sort | uniq -c -i > tmp1
```

This outputs the file as it should do, ignoring case, words less than 3 letters, punctuation and digits.

However i am now stump on how to pull out the palindromes from this, i thought a temp file might be the way, just don't know where to take it.

any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: `awk` can do everything you're using `tr` and `sed` for -- see the `gsub()` function in particular. No point in piping content between a whole bunch of separate processes when one can do the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash - Search .txt file for palindromes and count them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865316/bash-search-txt-file-for-palindromes-and-count-them)

Comment: Regarding the duplicate flag: This is the original post and the linked question is a duplicate, but since the linked question has better answers, it seemed better to close this question and keep the other one open.

Comment: This question relates to a courswork assignment (set by me) and posting a partial solution to the assignment and asking for solutions on stack exchange is a violation of the plagiarism and collusion regulations. If you have problems with getting the code working, ask me or the teaching assistants for help. Please can this question be deleted?

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, general-purpose deletion of a question leaves it visible to users with 10,000 rep or more. If you want it deleted more thoroughly, that requires moderator intervention. (That said, the general policy here is that we don't support deletion at the poster's request if the question or its answers are potentially helpful to others -- if someone was cheating/plagiarizing, this policy also helps to ensure they get caught, rather than deleting their question as soon as they have an answer and thus going undetected unless a 10k+ account is used to scan for such behavior).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# modify this to your needs; it should take your input on stdin, and return one word per
# line on stdout, in the same order if called more than once with the same input.
preprocess() {
  tr -d '[[:punct:][:digit:]@]' \
    | sed -E -e '/^(.)\1+$/d' \
    | tr -s '[[:space:]]' \
    | tr '[[:space:]]' '\n'
}

paste <(preprocess <"$1") <(preprocess <"$1" | rev) \
  | awk '$1 == $2 && (length($1) >= 3) { print $1 }' \
  | sort | uniq -c
```

The critical thing here is to paste together your input file with a stream that has each line from that input file reversed. This gives you two separate columns you can compare.

Comment: Thank you, how would this be placed in since i got a bunch of random words which werent palindromes?

Comment: Do you mean in the output? I'd like to see the associated input lines to reproduce that.

Comment: Again, I'd need to see the input. Works for me.

Comment: What the file (containing the words) im inputting? or my bash file

Comment: I've made some amendments to the code, but since I can't reproduce your problem in the first place (I only get palindromes as output), I certainly can't claim that they fix it.

Comment: Could you [gist](https://gist.github.com/) a transcript of, say, `cat pacheck; cat input; bash -x pacheck input` (assuming this file is saved as `pacheck`)? That would provide what I need to have a better idea of what's going on. (Or, even better, a 3-file gist with stdout and stderr of each command as a separate file).

Comment: Is it possible to get that to a txt file? i tried the > example.txt because its quite a long text. also your updated code kinda worked, it detected palidromes but not all of them, such as did, also iii appeared.

Comment: The output of `bash -x`, you mean? Sure; it's sent to stderr by default, so `bash -x pacheck input >log 2>&1`

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't trying to remove duplicated letters in that version. Frankly, that came across as awfully close to dumping all your homework assignment requirements in SO (which we frown on) vs asking a narrow technical question (which we welcome).

Comment: ...which is to say, the part you were having trouble with was identifying strings that are equal to themselves when reversed, and that's what I've done here.

Comment: Sorry about that i didnt know it was frown apon, however i should of expected that really, im sure i could figure out that part [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gtbbHQQn)

Comment: So, a few notes -- when I said `bash -x pacheck input`, the `pacheck` is the script. So what that will output when done correctly is a list of commands that bash runs when running the script with the input file as `$1`.

Comment: (that said, it's good to know what your input looks like -- my script expects it to be pre-normalized to one line per word, and obviously that's not the case here).

Comment: (also, I suggest gist instead of pastebin.com because the latter is ad-supported, and has a history of not being picky about whose ads they push; they've improved over the years, but better to patronize folks who've avoided intrusive -- or malware-laden -- advertising from the start).

Comment: From original version of code - [orig](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/6ee7f19ec294b4c9a2673f8052e1ec90/raw/c42031495956bd152d52da9a699477d1fdb552c6/log) New version of code - [new](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/2f65c94e52dcfc841d561a07260ce2c7/raw/ff3fbfe1c889fe10e892dcd9906569bc737c40a5/log2)

sorry i missed your last comment, ill redo the links

EDIT updated with gist

Comment: So, I've made some further enhancements, and from there documented the needs of the preprocessing function -- consider any further work necessary to get it to emit correct output with your input in mind an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated it look like its working now!

Comment: @JasonArcher, using awk's pipe functionality unnecessary is bad form. It implicitly invokes `sh -c`, which makes it hard to use correctly when parameterizing from data from untrusted sources -- and why start up a new shell as a child of `awk` when you already have a shell to start with?

Comment: @JasonArcher, ...also, the OP wants a count of how many times each word is seen. You don't get that with `sort -u` -- thus, we need `uniq -c`.