# Exclude words which only have one unique character BASH

Tags: regex, bash

Im trying to exclude words which only have one unique character (e.g. iiii, AAA). Words will be inputted through a txt file. I figure it may be able to be done with REGEX and see, however I don't know REGEX very well I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: This is for a homework problem relating to palindromes? Someone else already has a complete solution to it elsewhere.

Comment: ...well -- someone else asked, got a solution they acknowledged as working, and deleted their question rather than accept that answer. @LeviBensley, *ahem* -- note that the terms of service give the site an irrevocable license to display contributed content. Removing a question for reasons other than such being a poor contribution to the knowledgebase is liable to be reversed. (Context for users w/ permission to view deleted questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744958/bash-finding-palindromes-in-a-txt-file)

Comment: @DikranMarsupial, this may be of interest to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the first letter of the work, then use that to construct a regular expression that matches 1 or more occurrences of that letter.

```
while IFS= read -r word; do
    [[ $word =~ ^"${word:0:1}"+$ ]] && continue
    ...
done <<EOF
word1
word2
word3
...
EOF
```

Comment: Quoting the expansion should fix that.

Answer (score 0):

GNU grep support PCRE:

```
 grep -P -v '^(.)\1*$'
```

- `-P` PCRE
- `-v` invert match : filters matching lines
- `^` begin of line anchor, empty string
- `.` matches any character
- `\1` is a back reference to first group between `()`
- `$` begin of line anchor, empty string

Comment: One unique character. I guess `I` or `A` qualifies.