# Counting palindromes in a text file

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line, palindrome

Having followed this thread [BASH Finding palindromes in a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744958/bash-finding-palindromes-in-a-txt-file) I can't figure out what am I doing wrong with my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
search() {
tr -d '[[:punct:][:digit:]@]' \
| sed -E -e '/^(.)\1+$/d'      \
| tr -s '[[:space:]]'           \
| tr '[[:space:]]' '\n'
}

search "$1"

paste <(search <"$1") <(search < "$1" | rev)     \
| awk '$1 == $2 && (length($1) >=3) { print $1 }' \
| sort | uniq -c
```

All im getting from this script is output of the whole text file. I want to only output palindromes >=3 and count them such as

425 did

120 non

etc. My textfile is called sample.txt and everytime i run the script with: cat sample.txt | source palindrome I get message 'bash: : No such file or directory'.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of palindromes, or do you want count *for each palindrome* the number of occurences inside the text file?

Comment: This question relates to a courswork assignment (set by me) and posting a partial solution to the assignment and asking for solutions on stack exchange is a violation of the plagiarism and collusion regulations.  If you have problems with getting the code working, ask me or the teaching assistants for help.  Please can this question be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **awk** and **sed**

```
awk 'function palindrome(str) {len=length(str); for(k=1; k<=len/2+len%2; k++) { if(substr(str,k,1)!=substr(str,len+1-k,1)) return 0 } return 1 } {for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if(length($i)>=3){ gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"",$i); if(length($i)>=3) {$i=tolower($i); if(palindrome($i)) arr[$i]++ }} } } END{for(i in arr) print arr[i],i}' file | sed -E '/^[0-9]+ (.)\1+$/d'
```

Tested on **1.2GB** file and execution time was **~4m 40s** `(i5-6440HQ @ 2.60GHz/4 cores/16GB)`

**Explanation :**

```
awk '
    function palindrome(str)               # Function to check Palindrome
    {
        len=length(str); 
        for(k=1; k<=len/2+len%2; k++) 
        { 
            if(substr(str,k,1)!=substr(str,len+1-k,1)) 
            return 0 
        } 
        return 1 
    } 

    {
        for(i=1; i<=NF; i++)               # For Each field in a record
        {
            if(length($i)>=3)              # if length>=3
            { 
                gsub(/[^a-zA-Z]/,"",$i);   # remove non-alpha character from it
                if(length($i)>=3)          # Check length again after removal
                {
                    $i=tolower($i);        # Covert to lowercase
                    if(palindrome($i))     # Check if it's palindrome
                        arr[$i]++          # and store it in array
                }
            }
        } 
    } 

    END{for(i in arr) print arr[i],i}' file | sed -E '/^[0-9]+ (.)\1+$/d'
```

`sed -E '/^[0-9]+ (.)\1+$/d'` : From the final result check which strings are composed of just repeated chracters like `AAA`, `BBB` etc and remove them.

---

**Old Answer (Before EDIT)**

You can try below steps if you want to :

**Step 1 : Pre-processing**
Remove all unnecessary chars and store the result in temp file

```
tr -dc 'a-zA-Z\n\t ' <file | tr ' ' '\n' > temp
```

`tr -dc 'a-zA-Z\n\t '` This will remove all except letters,`\n`,`\t`, space

`tr ' ' '\n'`  This will convert space to `\n` to separate each word in newlines

**Step-2: Processing**

```
grep -wof temp <(rev temp)  | sed -E -e '/^(.)\1+$/d' | awk 'length>=3 {a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i; }'
```

`grep -wof temp <(rev temp)` This will give you all palindromes
`-w` : Select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.
For example : `level` won't match with `levelAAA`
`-o` : Print only the matched group
`-f` : To use each string in `temp` file as pattern to search in `<(rev temp)`

`sed -E -e '/^(.)\1+$/d'`: This will remove words formed of same letters like `AAA`, `BBBBB`

`awk 'length>=3 {a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i; }'` : This will filter words having `length>=3` and counts their frequency and finally prints the result

**Example :**

**Input File :**

```
$ cat file
kayak nalayak bob dad , pikachu. meow !! bhow !! 121 545 ding dong AAA BBB done
kayak nalayak bob dad , pikachu. meow !! bhow !! 121 545 ding dong AAA BBB done
kayak nalayak bob dad , pikachu. meow !! bhow !! 121 545 ding dong AAA BBB done
```

**Output:**

```
$ tr -dc 'a-zA-Z\n\t ' <file | tr ' ' '\n' > temp
$ grep -wof temp <(rev temp)  | sed -E -e '/^(.)\1+$/d' | awk 'length>=3 {a[$1]++} END{ for(i in a) print a[i],i; }' 
3 dad
3 kayak
3 bob
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick Perl alternative:

```
perl -0nE 'for( /(\w{3,})/g ){ $a{$_}++ if $_ eq reverse($_)}
           END {say "$_ $a{$_}" for keys %a}'
```

- in Perl, `$_` should be read as "**it**".
- `for( /(\w{3,})/g )`  ... for all relevant words (may need some work to reject false positives like "12a21")
- `if $_ eq reverse($_)`  ... if **it** is palindrome
- `END {say "$_ $a{$_}" for...}` ... tell us all the **it**s and **it**s number

\thanks{sokowi,batMan}

Comment: It won't produce the desired result as it will consider digits and words like `AAA` which OP doesn't want. BTW nice solution .

Comment: @batMan, thank you. >"AAA"  I have not seen any restriction about avoiding AAA . >... "digits" -- you are completely right!

Comment: @Socowi, thank you. If I remember correctly, `reverse` is used for arrays, not for strings. `reverse("abc") = "abc"`

Comment: @Socowi, my bad! you are right!! in atomic context, reverse("abc") = "cba". I will improve the solution acordins to your comment.

Answer (score 2):

## Running the Script

The script expects that the file is given as an argument. The script does not read stdin.

Remove the line `search "$1"` in the middle of the script. It is not part of the linked answer.

Make the script executable using `chmod u+x path/to/palindrome`.

Call the script using `path/to/palindrome path/to/sample.txt`. If all the files are in the current working directory, then the command is

```
./palindrome sample.txt
```

## Alternative Script

Sometimes the linked script works and sometimes it doesn't. I haven't found out why. However, I wrote an alternative script which does the same and is also a bit cleaner:

```
#! /bin/bash
grep -Po '\w{3,}' "$1" |  grep -Evw '(.)\1*' | sort > tmp-words
grep -Fwf <(rev tmp-words) tmp-words | uniq -c
rm tmp-words
```

Save the script, make it executable, and call it with a file as its first argument.